# Почему на IOS 9.3 не работают flexbox?

Tags: html, css3, flexbox

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Здравствуйте почему на IOS 9.3 не работают flex box не центрирует при помощи
`display: flex;
justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;` ?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Слелайте пожалуйста скриншот с iOS девайса и ПК, чтобы можно было сравнить.

Comment: сделал скриншоты

Comment: http://caniuse.com/ - посмотрите, может нужно префиксы добавить?

Comment: gulp сам подставляет префиксы !